# How to get Tomcat logs in Splunk 7.2.0?

Tags: java, tomcat, splunk, splunk-sdk

I am working in machine learning recently. My goal is need to see logs from locally installed Tomcat in Splunk search.

I installed Apache Tomcat at a drive in my local machine. Then opened Splunk instance, I installed Tomcat add ons, followed this instruction (splunk docs), created inputs.conf file and placed it in Splunk_TA_tomcat/local folder. Then restarted Splunk. After I went to search page, I entered this command `sourcetype = tomcat:access:log`. I got nothing.

```
1. Create an inputs.conf file in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/Splunk_TA_tomcat/local.

2. Add the following stanzas. Modify the directory name if necessary to use the actual directory your Tomcat files are stored in.

 [monitor:///Applications/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/catalina.*.log]
 disabled = false
 followTail = false
 index = main
 sourcetype = tomcat:runtime:log

 [monitor:///Applications/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/localhost.*.log]
 disabled = false
 followTail = false
 index = main
 sourcetype = tomcat:runtime:log

 [monitor:///Applications/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/manager.*.log]
 disabled = false
 followTail = false
 index = main
 sourcetype = tomcat:runtime:log

 [monitor:///Applications/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/host-manager.*.log]
 disabled = false
 followTail = false
 index = main
 sourcetype = tomcat:runtime:log

 [monitor:///Applications/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/localhost_access_log.*.txt]
 disabled = false
 followTail = false
 index = main
 sourcetype = tomcat:access:log
```

[image]

Comment: Did you configure the outputs.conf ? Is something arriving in your local splunk (making an * search in your main index).

Comment: i do not know how to search?

Comment: can you please help me ?

Comment: Do a search like this "index=main". Do you see your logs ?

Comment: yeah i am getting logs

Comment: What sourcetype do you have for theses logs ? Are they the log of your tomcat ?